# Why do we treat $\frac{-\infty}{\infty}$ the same as $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ when using L'Hopital's Rule?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why we treat the cases $\frac{-\infty}{\infty}$ &  $\frac{\infty}{-\infty}$ as the case $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$?, where did the -ve sign go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because if we have a limit $$\lim\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ where $$\lim f(x)=\infty\\\lim g(x)=-\infty$$

(a situation we sometimes - but this is sloppy writing - call $\frac\infty{-\infty}$),

then

$$\lim\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = - \lim\frac{f(x)}{-g(x)}$$

if the limits exist. The right version is of the "type" $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, so we can use L'Hospital to get

$$- \lim\frac{f(x)}{-g(x)} = - \lim\frac{f'(x)}{(-g(x))'} = - \lim\frac{f'(x)}{-g'(x)} = \lim\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$